# How can I Cleanly Loop Through Values for Both Class Members and Constructor?

Tags: typescript

I am currently working on a class to describe `Weapon`s. Each attribute of a `Weapon` looks like this:

```
interface WeaponAttribute {
  current: number;
  max: number;
  min: number;
}
```

The attributes each `Weapon` must have are described here (19 in total):

```
type BaseAttributes = 'attack' | 'endurance' | 'speed' | 'magicalPower';

type ElementalAttributes = 'fire' | 'holy' | 'ice' | 'thunder' | 'wind';

type MonsterTypes =
  | 'beast'
  | 'dragon'
  | 'mage'
  | 'marine'
  | 'metal'
  | 'mimic'
  | 'plant'
  | 'rock'
  | 'sky'
  | 'undead';

type AntiMonstertTypeAttributes = `anti${Capitalize<MonsterTypes>}`;

type WeaponAttributeKeys =
  | BaseAttributes
  | ElementalAttributes
  | AntiMonstertTypeAttributes;
```

The class itself should accept a `Map` with all keys in `WeaponAttributeKeys` and `Partial` `WeaponAttribute`s, but the class itself should have all keys in `WeaponAttributeKeys` with corresponding values of type `WeaponAttribute`. What I have feels close, but TypeScript isn't happy.

```
type WeaponWithCompleteAttributes = {
  [key in WeaponAttributeKeys]: WeaponAttribute;
};

type WeaponWithPartialAttributes = Map<
  WeaponAttributeKeys,
  Partial<WeaponAttribute>
>;

export default class Weapon implements WeaponWithCompleteAttributes { // ERROR
  constructor(weapon: WeaponWithPartialAttributes) {
    weapon.forEach(({ min = 0, max = 99, current = min }, key) => {
      this[key] = { current, max, min }; // ERROR
    });
  }
}
```

```
Class 'Weapon' incorrectly implements interface 'WeaponWithCompleteAttributes'.
  Type 'Weapon' is missing the following properties from type 'WeaponWithCompleteAttributes': attack, endurance, speed, magicalPower, and 15 more.

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'WeaponAttributeKeys' can't be used to index type 'Weapon'.
  Property 'attack' does not exist on type 'Weapon'.
```

I'm not sure how to properly iterate over all the keys and save myself from having to declare everything manually.

Comment: [here](https://tsplay.dev/mZVaKm) you have the easiest way to accomplish it.

Comment: This doesn't really do what I would like. Ideally, every attribute would be a property on the class itself, and not wrapped in an additional object layer.